# How to Report Downloadable products? (Music store)

Tags: attributes, category, reports, downloadable

I'm not sure whats the best way to achieve this, I'm developing a music store which will have a catalog of number of independent record labels releases. Typically an album(downloadable product) will belong to an artist, an artist will release under a record label. My first question is what do I use to represent that hierarchy, Categories or Attributes or other? Which is also report friendly .

The report will be per record label and should contain sales figures per artist and album.

Question two: Is it possible/recommended to use external tools like Jasper Reports and how?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on the same thing at the moment and decided to use attributes and make them visible on the front end. That way you can specify custom values per artist or label by simply creating a new attribute set...

Good luck!

Comment: Thank You :-) I will try that as well and accept the answer if all goes well.

Comment: What are you doing in terms of reporting? Like reporting sales that a Label has.